# Tried everything, ADB is not detecting my nexus on windows 7

Tags: android, testing, adb

I'm trying to add my external device(nexus 5) to test.
for that
1) I have installed Google USB drivers
2) set environment variables as ANDROID_HOME & PATH
3) set android:debugger="true" in manifest, same in gradle.
4) if I list devices connected to ADB in command prompt, gets no devices.
5) Driver for nexus 5 is uptodate as i have checked from device manager of windows 7.
6) enabled usb debugging on my phone in developer options.

It seems nothing is working on my way here, how can I test my camera/bluetooth app on my nexus 5? please, help.

Comment: Reinstall drivers from adbdrivers.com, then connect phone on debugging mode(go to developer option and enable usb debugging), if not works then switch to Ptp or viceversa. Hopefully it works

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816964/how-to-get-usb-debugging-on-android-6-working

Comment: What version of Android are you on?  I'm having the same issue on OSX with Android 6 - wsa working perfectly before.

Comment: Android 6 only. but things are pretty different for mac os. what tricks you have tried till?

Answer (score 0):

Did you trychanging the usb cable? That did the trick  for my moto x when i was trying to connect it for debugging purposes.  It did not work with the usb cable that came with my phone but worked with another cable that I bought.