# How to get usb debugging on android 6 working?

Tags: android, adb

So I used to have this working on 5, after an update to Android 6 I'm unable to get USB debugging to work. Anyone else run into this?

- I've enabled USB debugging on the device.
- I've tried three different USB cables
- there are no options under storage & USB for, well, USB
- I tried downloading the LG G4 unified drivers for OSX

Comment: I've never had to install drivers for a phone when developing on OSX...that's strange that you're having issues...

Comment: This is not programming related, so might be better asked on http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Me neither, but came across a forum post suggesting someone else solved it this way, sadly no dice.  @cricket_007, while this is specifically a programming issue, it is a toolchain issue, for which I'm specifically looking for the help and insight of other developers, thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused then. Your title is how to enable usb debugging, but the content of the question says you've already enabled it, so I suggest you more clearly explain the problem. Just your computer can't see the device? And it used to work?

Comment: ok title edited.  Yeah it used to work, pre the upgrade to marshmallow, now adb see's nothing, and I get no setup options on the device as I did previously when connecting with a USB cable.

Comment: Still no joy here, and I've noticed the question popping up on other forums, I'll update if I make any progress

Comment: Despite trying multiple cables, this landed up being a cable issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try revoking the debugging authorizations:

- Unplug the device
- Go into Settings > Developer Options and tap on "Revoke USB debugging authorizations"
- Click OK on the resulting dialog
- Plug the device in again and see if you get the ADB authorization dialog

Comment: thanks, but its still not working, Its almost as if it never changes out of charging mode.  (Despite changing to PTP  - which si the right one  - I've also tried the different modes).  no luck.

Comment: @pushplaybang: Have you confirmed that any of your USB cables are good for more than charging? For example, do they work for data transfer with other sorts of devices? Cables that come with things like USB battery packs sometimes are only set up for charging, not data.

Comment: Yeah, I was using the same cables previously, with the same device on Android 5,

Answer (score 1):

You might consider to change adb port in you pc.

1. add "ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT" and "5045" as new environment variable and its value.
2. Restart adb using adb kill-server and adb start-server.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings -> About phone.
Go to the bottom item "Build number" and click on it few times util you will see the toat: You are a developer now.

Now go back and you will see a new item called "Developer options".
Click on it.
Enable "USB debugging" option.

Comment: OP said they'd already enabled USB debugging on the device though.

Comment: Yeah I have already enabled USB debugging thanks, still no dice.  I've had this working as recently as a week ago, but after an upgrade, there are no connection options and ADB no longer sees the device.